# HTTP MessageFlow not working on Linux with MQ 7.1 and Broker 8.0.0.1

Tags: ibm-mq, messagebroker, ibm-integration-bus

I am working on Linux and I have MQ version 7.1 and Broker 8.0.0.1 installed on the machine. I have one Http flow that I am not able to test/run. The same flow if I deploy on AIX.. I am able to run successfully, but when I try to do this in case of Linux, I get a timeout as nothing is received at HTTPReply node.

the flow is like:

HTTPInput --> Compute --> MQOutput --> Compute --> MQOutput(Queue 1)

MQInput --> MQGet(Queue 1) --> Compute -->HTTPReply

In syslog, I get this on Linux:

```
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP2628E: Exception condition detected on input node 'com.dcx.bib.test.http.HTTPBIBGateway.MQInput'. : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbCommonInputNode.cpp: 1982: ImbCommonInputNode::run: ComIbmMQInputNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_9
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP2628E: Exception condition detected on input node 'com.dcx.bib.test.http.HTTPBIBGateway.MQInput'. : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/DataFlowEngine/ImbCommonInputNode.cpp: 1982: ImbCommonInputNode::run: ComIbmMQInputNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_9
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.dcx.bib.test.http.HTTPBIBGateway.HTTP Reply1'. : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSReplyNode.cpp: 932: ImbWSReplyNode::evaluate: ComIbmWSReplyNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_11
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP2230E: Error detected whilst processing a message in node 'com.dcx.bib.test.http.HTTPBIBGateway.HTTP Reply1'. : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSReplyNode.cpp: 932: ImbWSReplyNode::evaluate: ComIbmWSReplyNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_11
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP3143S: Message does not contain valid HTTP context information : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSReplyNode.cpp: 507: ImbWSReplyNode::evaluate: ComIbmWSReplyNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_11
WebSphere Broker v8001[21605]: (NSPZPAI1.BIBTEST1)[121]BIP3143S: Message does not contain valid HTTP context information : NSPZPAI1.8f1bda8b-3c01-0000-0080-89b5509992f7: /build/slot1/S800_P/src/WebServices/WSLibrary/ImbWSReplyNode.cpp: 507: ImbWSReplyNode::evaluate: ComIbmWSReplyNode: com/dcx/bib/test/http/HTTPBIBGateway#FCMComposite_1_11
```

I am very sure that exactly the same works fine on AIX with the same environment, then Why Am I getting this error on Linux?
There can be no problem in the message flow if it works end to end on AIX, then what can be the problem on Linux? If the issue is OS based, then what should I check?Please suggest.

---

@nitgeek .. I placed a trace node before HTTP Reply but got nothing as the message is going out through the no message terminal of the MQGet node.. When I placed the trace node just before and after the MQGet node.. I got the following in both :

```
( ['MQROOT' : 0x76fa1f0]
  (0x01000000:Name):Properties = ( ['MQPROPERTYPARSER' : 0x75ccfa0]
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageSet             = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageType            = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MessageFormat          = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Encoding               = 273 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CodedCharSetId         = 1208 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Transactional          = FALSE (BOOLEAN)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Persistence            = TRUE (BOOLEAN)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CreationTime           = GMTTIMESTAMP '2013-02-04 10:43:55.720' (GMTTIMESTAMP)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ExpirationTime         = -1 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Priority               = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyIdentifier        = X'414d51204e53505a504149312020202016efbfbd0a511607' (BLOB)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyProtocol          = 'MQ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Topic                  = NULL
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ContentType            = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceType     = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceToken    = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourcePassword = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentitySourceIssuedBy = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedType     = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedToken    = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedPassword = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):IdentityMappedIssuedBy = '' (CHARACTER)
  )
  (0x01000000:Name):MQMD       = ( ['MQHMD' : 0x73cf7c0]
    (0x03000000:NameValue):SourceQueue      = 'PAI.JUNIT.REPLY' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Transactional    = FALSE (BOOLEAN)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Encoding         = 273 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CodedCharSetId   = 1208 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Format           = '        ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Version          = 2 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Report           = 64 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MsgType          = 8 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Expiry           = -1 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Feedback         = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Priority         = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Persistence      = 1 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MsgId            = X'414d51204e53505a5041493120202020168f0a510a880620' (BLOB)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):CorrelId         = X'414d51204e53505a504149312020202016efbfbd0a511607' (BLOB)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):BackoutCount     = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyToQ         = '                                                ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ReplyToQMgr      = 'NSPZPAI1                                        ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):UserIdentifier   = 'mqbrkrs     ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):AccountingToken  = X'0539393736360000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006' (BLOB)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ApplIdentityData = '                                ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):PutApplType      = 6 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):PutApplName      = 'java                        ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):PutDate          = DATE '2013-02-04' (DATE)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):PutTime          = GMTTIME '10:43:55.720' (GMTTIME)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):ApplOriginData   = '    ' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):GroupId          = X'000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000' (BLOB)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MsgSeqNumber     = 1 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):Offset           = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):MsgFlags         = 0 (INTEGER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):OriginalLength   = -1 (INTEGER)
  )
  (0x01000000:Name):BLOB       = ( ['none' : 0x76c5da0]
    (0x03000000:NameValue):UnknownParserName = '' (CHARACTER)
    (0x03000000:NameValue):BLOB              = X'3c3f786d6c2076657273696f6e3d22312e30223f3e3c746573745f7265706f72742074657374636173653d22424942334e4f444530315343312220737461727454696d653d224d6f6e204665622030342030353a34333a35352045535420323031332220656e6454696d653d224d6f6e204665622030342030353a34333a353520455354203230313322207375636365737366756c3d2274727565223e3c636173652069643d22424942334e4f4445303173633122207374617475733d2273756363657373223e3c2f636173653e3c2f746573745f7265706f72743e' (BLOB)
  )
)
```

Please suggest where am I going wrong.

Comment: *P.S. I also have a .FDC file created in /var/mqm/errors .. but I am not able to comprehend it. Can somebody suggest something?

Comment: Can you run a trace and put at least the last part?

Comment: @nitgeek Could you please elaborate a little more.. What do you mean by run a trace.. I am new to MQ and Broker.. So.. kindly suggest.

Comment: Put it in answer, to get it more readable

Answer (score 0):

For running a trace run below commands from command prompt.

```
    mqsichangetrace broker_name -u -e execution_grp_name -l none -f  com.mns.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104(Flow name with schema) -c 5000
    mqsichangetrace broker_name -u -e execution_grp_name -l debug -f com.mns.ms.sap.IP1_PFT_1_VNDR_MNG_P104(Flow name with schema) -c 5000
    mqsireadlog broker_name -u -e execution_grp_name -f -o trace.xml
    mqsiformatlog -i trace.xml -o formattrace.txt
```

Read the formattrace.txt file and post here the last part only, as the file may be huge.

If possible put a trace node before HTTP reply node and in "Pattern" of the Trace node provide:

```
${Root}
${Environment}
```

This should give us enough information about what's happening in your flow.
Once done, post the value of Root and environment value from the trace file.

I think there is something wrong with your header details.